# explanation to java as a secure language?

Tags: java, c++, metaprogramming

Can somebody please help me in understanding what are the following attacks and how does java make these attacks impossible:

> 1. overrunning the routine stack- a common attack of worms and viruses
> 2. corrupting memory outside its own process space
> 3. reading or writing files without permission.

I am well versed in c/c++ and starting with java so please help me understand these.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, the security issues are more a question of the
implementation, rather than the language.  Java does impose some
security checks (bounds checking, etc.) that are optional (and
very expensive in runtime) in C++.  With regards to your
specific issues:

1. I presume this refers to the classical buffer overrun issue,
   which often was a problem in C.  In C++, we use `std::vector`,
   which can (and usually does, at least when the correct compiler
   options are given) do the same checks as Java.  If, on the other
   hand, it does refer to stack overflow (e.g. as a result of too
   deep recursion), then because the stack of the JVM is not the
   machine stack, Java can do extra checks, and also guarantee an
   out of memory exception in the case of stack overflow.  (This is
   also possible in C++, but I don't know of a compiler which does
   it.  And the operating systems don't always make it that easy.)
2. This is an OS issue, not a language issue.  Modern OS's
   doesn't allow programs to access memory outside their own
   process space, so neither Java nor C++ allow it.
3. As above, this is an OS issue, not a language issue, and
   modern OS's enforce it relatively well, regardless of whether
   the program is written in Java or in C++.

In summary, both 2 and 3 are impossible, regardless of the
language, and 1 won't occur in well written C++ (although it was
a problem in the past with C).

Comment: thanks for giving such a simple looking and complete answer..

Answer (score 5):

Java is a reasonably secure language because of a few reasons, focusing mostly on your 3 points, Java is more secure than other languages, predominantly because it executes bytecode instructions in its own virtual machine, not native code. It does not allow out of bounds array access, and has no pointer access. This pretty much answers your first 2 points.
As for reading and writing without permission I am not sure what you mean by that. Inherently file reading and writing is controlled at an operating system level. Without some exploit to gain more permission than it should, no matter what language it is written in, a program cannot write or read to files the OS prohibits it from. If you mean without permission from an application standpoint, from say a plugin system, then you would need to look into adding a security manager or your own vetting to prevent plugins or modules from altering files under your applications process.

Comment: thanks a lot..u pretty much answered my question and about file reading and writing I read it somewhere that and e.g. in c++ we can pretty much open any file in our code by simple commands, is there any way in java to protect the file?

Comment: The file is protected by the JVM, and can only be opened if the JVM has permission, there is no way for a Java application to bypass this without calling C++ code. As for bypassing any file with C++, I haven't heard of this happening, it would seem like a pretty big oversight to me, but I am not a c++ developer.

Comment: kk...thanks for your answer..actually there is no concept like jvm in c++ and you can access any file by writing simple code to access that i.e. there is only a compiler so yeah now I have understood to a great extent what you want to say...

Comment: one thing more can you please explain the first point by giving an example and in some detail..

Comment: As mentioned by the post below me, in Java there is no way to break out of the stack by editing the surrounding memory, or causing it to overflow. If the stack gets bigger than a certain size, an error will be thrown. As for file access, the operating system will still stop you from doing this.

Comment: WHile the JVM nitionally executes byte code, the JIT will compile the code to native machine code as required (some times more than once as the usage changes) so you get similar performance to that produced by a C++ compiler.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Depending on the program, you can get better or worse performance.  Of course, nothing in the C++ standard forbids compiling to a byte code and doing runtime analysis. And in the past, at least, there has been a C++ compiler whose generated code was as secure as that of Java---it did full bounds checking, etc.  One of the goals of "undefined behavior" was to allow such implementations.

Comment: @james kanze if I make a file in c++ and I want to access it there is no way if you give me the file and still I am able to access it securely apart from making a copy of it...the changes I will make in the file after accessing it will be permanent and thus according to me accessing file in c++ is not very secure...correct me if i am wrong..

Comment: @JamesKanze There are tools for C++ which you build in the program to detect issues like data structure overruns, memory leaks etc, without using byte code.

Comment: @mohitcse C++ is not as secure for running untrusted code.  It is also more difficult to ensure that a program exposed to the internet cannot be broken easily.  You can write unsecure programs in Java BTW, it's a little more obvious when you do. :)

Comment: @mohitcse I don't understand what you are trying to say concerning file modification, but file handling in C++ and in Java is almost identical, and depend more on the OS than on the language.  When I create a file, I can give you (or others) the right to access it, either read-only or read-write; it's up to me.  The OS enforces the rights I determine.

Comment: @PeterLawrey In the past, there was even a C/C++ compiler which did full bounds checking, including on C style arrays.  I don't know if they still exist, however.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Java protects against certain types of errors allowing undesired access to data within the program.  C++ largely leaves this protection to the programmer, but someone used to writing native C++ will do it instinctively.  Something like a `char buffer[N];` sticks out like a sore thumb in C++, and would never be written (as a local variable, at any rate) by a professional C++ programer.

Comment: @JamesKanze This protects you when you have a trusted, experienced C++ developer.  Say instead you have a compiled progam you loaded off the internet from a web site you don't know if you should trust.  The question would be; how can you run that code in a secure way?  In Java that happens all the time. For C++ programs people do run them, but not securely.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I would say that if you run code downloaded from an untrusted site, there's no way you can be secure.  Again, the language doesn't enter into it.  (Unless you're talking about the difficulty of doing code review.  While it's possible to write unreadable programs in any language, C++ does offer some particularly powerful features for hiding what the code is doing.)

Comment: @JamesKanze  When you view a web page with an applet, javascript, or flash, you are running code downloaded from a web site and running it.  You wouldn't consider downloaded an EXE and running it automatically.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Good point.  I am assuming (trusting, perhaps mistakenly, the authors of the brower or the plugin) that these are interpreted languages, with only limited powers.  The case of an applet (Java) is interesting; I would hope that it is being run by a special JVM built into the browser, which doesn't allow it access to all of the usual features (e.g. `Runtime.exec`, or anything which would create a file).

Comment: Java Applets (those run in a browser) are very restricted by default, although you can gain additional permission for stuff like network communication by signing your jar with a security certificate.

Answer (score 4):

Security is a relative thing. As Java runs in a Virtual Machine it can protect it self for some of the classical problems seen in C.

> overrunning the routine stack- a common attack of worms and viruses

Java has a defined behaviour of throwing a StackOverflowError and you cannot bypass this.

> corrupting memory outside its own process space

IMHO, This is really an OS consideration.  Your OS can protect your processes from modifying memory of other processes even in C.  Java protects you my not letting you access arbitary memory locations whether the OS provides this facility or not.  Most modern OSes provide this protection.

> reading or writing files without permission.

Again your OS can protect you from doing this in C and should be your first line of defense.  What Java does is allow you to run code which is not trusted and protect your files even if you can access them, but stop one of your programs from accessing them.  Java has two mechanisms, The SecurityManager and AccessControl.

Comment: As an undergraduate student my question is that while declaring dynamic data structures in which we dont know what can be the maximum maemory occupied how does 2nd point apply.. I will be grateful if you can help me understanding it by a suitable example.

Comment: Java has a defined behaviour when a memory limit is reached, it throws an OutOfMemoryError.  While you can handle this, you cannot avoid it preventing you allocating more memory.

Comment: then I am very surprised at c++ not having this feature..is it? and this memory limit will vary code to code so does the developer fix this memory limit?

Comment: The default limit varies based on the machine.  Generally, it's a good idea use only require a fraction of the memory you use for efficiency purposes. As 32 GB of memory costs less than $200, memory it's as expensive as it used to be. ;)  BTW C has a memory usage limit you can specify with `ulimit` It's not handled as elegeantly ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey C++ also throws an exception (`std::bad_alloc`) when trying to allocate more memory than is available.  Java and C++ are more or less identical in this respect.  On the other hand, I think Java guarantees this in cases of stack overflow as well (which is undefined behavior in C++).  Perhaps more significantly, well written C++ programs don't use dynamic allocation nearly as much as Java (where all user defined types are always dynamically allocated).

Comment: @JamesKanze Well written C++ programs tend to use the stack more, something which is not an option in Java. :|

Comment: @james kanze but while dealing with trees and other similar types in c++ we very frequently use dynamic types and I have never come across an exception like this.. can you please explain with an example ?

Comment: @mohitcse it's possible the limit was so high you never reached it. ;)

Comment: It is worth adding that the JVM can perform escape analysis which can eliminate heap allocations (effectively using the stack instead) and is impressive when it works ;)

Comment: well going by your arguments I am very impressed by the way java works and will definitely like to go into detail mechanism of how things go about here @ peter lawrey...:)

Comment: @mohitcse The JVM is fairly impressive engineering.  The feature I find most impressive is the ablity to inline virtual methods dynamically, even those compiled after the program started running ;)  This all works even if you unload a module. i.e. the inlined code is uninlined dynamically and largely transparently.

Comment: let me go through  about this feature first and then I would like to comment on it...by the way it is looking impressive indeed..:)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20994/discussion-between-mohitcse-and-peter-lawrey)

Comment: @PeterLawrey `ulimit` has nothing to do with C; it is an OS feature.  Set it too low, and Java won't run.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Concerning stack usage, it depends.  In well written programs (Java or C++), stack overflow will only occur because of unbound recursion; neither language encourages (and Java doesn't allow) large data structures on the stack.  Both `std::vector` (in C++) and Java's arrays use dynamically allocated memory for the data elements.

Comment: @mohitcse If you try to allocate more memory than the OS will give you (in C++), you will get an `std::bad_alloc` exception.  Of course, if the OS is broken, and "gives" you memory that it doesn't have, and then causes the program to crash when you try to use it, there's not much any language can do about it.  (And there are OS's which do this.)